# How to cast java lang long to entity class in SpringBoot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

> I create a application , When I go to update a column in my DataBase I
> get such type of error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.entity.DepositMaterial cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.entity.DepositMaterial is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.findByUserId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.service.DepositService.updateDeposit(DepositService.kt:43) ~[main/:na]
    at com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.controller.AdminMaterialController.updateMaterial(AdminMaterialController.kt:49) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:90) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

> DepositMaterial.kt

```
package com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.entity

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class DepositMaterial(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "depositId")
    val id: Long = -1,
    val userId: Long = -1,
    val totalPieces: Long = -1,
    val deposit: Long = -1,
    val pending: Long = totalPieces-deposit,
    val workStatus: Boolean = false

)
```

> ReqUpdateDeposit.kt

```
package com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.request

data class ReqUpdateDeposit(
    val userId:Long=-1,
    val pending:Long=-1,
)
```

> DepositService.kt

```
package com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.service

import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.entity.DepositMaterial
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.request.ReqDeposit
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.request.ReqUpdateDeposit
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.repository.DepositRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import kotlin.jvm.Throws

@Service
class DepositService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositRepository: DepositRepository
    
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun updateDeposit(request : ReqUpdateDeposit):DepositMaterial{
        val existingUser = depositRepository.findByUserId(request.userId)
        if (existingUser == request.userId){
            if (request.pending.equals(0)){
                depositRepository.updateWorkStatus(true,request.userId)
            }else{
                println("you have still pending materials")
            }
        }
        else{
            println("Enter a valid userId")
        }
        return DepositMaterial()
    }

}
```

> DepositMaterialRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.repository

import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.entity.DepositMaterial
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import javax.transaction.Transactional

interface DepositRepository : JpaRepository<DepositMaterial, Long> {
    /** find user by userID*/
    fun findByUserId(userId: Long):Long

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update DepositMaterial d set d.workStatus =:workStatus where d.userId =:userId")
    fun updateWorkStatus(@RequestParam("workStatus")workStatus: Boolean,userId: Long)
}
```

> AdminMaterialController.kt

```
package com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.controller

import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.request.ReqDeposit
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.request.ReqUpdateDeposit
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.request.ReqWithdrawMaterial
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.response.ResMessage
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.response.RespDeposit
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.model.response.RespWithdrawMaterial
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.service.DepositService
import com.nilmani.jobworkmanagement.service.WithdrawMaterialService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
class AdminMaterialController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var materialService: WithdrawMaterialService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositService: DepositService
    
    @PatchMapping("/verifyWorkstatus")
    fun updateMaterial(@ModelAttribute request: ReqUpdateDeposit):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val updateWork = depositService.updateDeposit(request)
        return ResponseEntity(ResMessage("Update success full"),HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

> What is the  reason for this issue , No where I cast the long variable
> with the entity class ,I Just call the entity class variables to
> access and update the DepositMaterial workStatus Column

Comment: Try adding the @RequestParam annotation to the `userId` parameter as well in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code

```
val existingUser = depositRepository.findByUserId(request.userId)
if (existingUser == request.userId){
```

You are comparing a `DepositMaterial`(existingUser) Object to a long object (request.userId). Which is wrong. Also why you need to compare it while you already got the entity from repository. Also since you defined id as Long (not primitive type) you need to use equals. Anyway you can compare like this

```
if (existingUser.id.equals(request.userId)){
```

Comment: These numbers should be compared with equals()
    
    if (existingUser.id.equals(request.userId)) {

Comment: you are right since it's not defined as primitive it should be equal. updated my answer